# Can't get Namespacing to work in PHPUnit tests using PSR4

Tags: php, unit-testing, namespaces, composer-php, phpunit

Currently, I am in the process of trying to create a PHP library using the PSR4 Namespacing standard. I can't get PHPUnit test suites to work correctly in my standalone library. As seen by the error displayed below, it seems that my understanding of Namespacing is incorrect. What am I doing wrong, is this a Namespacing, PHPUnit test error or an implementation issue?

```
SearchTest::testIsThereAnySyntaxError
Error: Class 'Purencoool\Search\Search' not found
```

The Json composer filename autoload Namespacing

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Purencool\\Search\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Purencool\\Search\\": "tests"
        }
    }
```

The PHPUnit test

```
  public function testIsThereAnySyntaxError()
  {
    $var = new Purencoool\Search\Search;
    $this->assertTrue(is_object($var));
    unset($var);
  }
```

To run the tests and see the file structure goto https://github.com/purencool/search

I am testing it using PHP version

```
PHP 7.3.20 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 23:55:30) ( NTS )
```

Comment: If `\Purencool\Search` is what's in `src/`, then `\Purencoool\Search\Search` should be in `src/Search.php`. I'm guessing `"Purencool\\": "src"` is what you meant, or just `Purencoool\Search` (as a full qualified class name) if `Search` should be your base namespace anyway. Note that I'm often myself mixing things up with these mappings so I might be mistaken.

Comment: So are you saying that my namespace should be ` "Purencool\\": "src" ` in composer.json and directory structure should be `src/Purencool/Search/Search.php`?

Comment: Hey thanks, I have just made the following commits, but I still get the same error https://github.com/purencool/search/commit/a5f1cae42c3df1ba347a32dcbd0de466d173c8f1

Comment: Thanks again, I made the changes you suggested https://github.com/purencool/search/commit/3390d78c8517f5815181a9a77e031bd1965dd2d3 and still get the following error `1) SearchTest::testIsThereAnySyntaxError
Error: Class 'Purencoool\Search' not found
`

Comment: No no no, I meant there is literally is one additional `o` (as in the letter `o`) in `Purencoool`. There are three o's. Your name/namespace have only two. Should be `new Purencool\Search\Search`.

Comment: Sorry I completely miss understood I have made the changes https://github.com/purencool/search/commit/3390d78c8517f5815181a9a77e031bd1965dd2d3. But the test still run an error `1) SearchTest::testIsThereAnySyntaxError
Error: Class 'Purencool\Search\Search' not found
`

Comment: You probably forgot to run `composer install` (though `composer dump-autoload` should be enough) after updating composer.json. Anyway, this chain of comments is getting way too long, I'm going to remove some of my earlier ones.

Comment: https://github.com/purencool/search/commit/cce8d218e71007c1ff52f5f71c66467dd9a9fb3a have a look at this commit

Comment: After running  ` composer dump-autoload ` it worked

Comment: You can answer the question if you like